# Hover com imagem

Tags: html, css

Não teve jeito, as setas do *slider* do projeto terão que ser em *png*.

Hoje estou fazendo assim (parte do código):

```
.banner_home_inferior .owl-next {
  right: -6px;
  background: url(/images/setas_novas.png) no-repeat !important;
  background-position: -55px 0px !important;
  height: 89px !important;
  width: 48px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin-top: -44.5px !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  font-size: 0 !important;
}

.banner_home_inferior .owl-next:hover {
  background: url(/images/setas_novas_hover.png) no-repeat !important;
  background-position: -55px 0px !important;
}
```

Porém, ao passar o mouse pela primeira vez, tem um *delay* para trocar as imagens.

Existe alguma técnica de fazer uma imagem que exibe a parte superior e ao passar o mouse, exibe a parte inferior?

Comment: Acredito que seja o tempo para carregar a imagem, são imagens grandes?

Answer (score 2):

Sim existe uma técnica, chama `Sprite` e vc faz trocando o `background-position`, porem as imagem precisam estar no mesmo .png ou .jpg etc...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a imagem que vou usar no exemplo, repare que ela tem várias imagens em uma só. E no `:hover` usando o `background-position` vou troca-las.

Veja o exemplo prático

```css
div {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HLqp.png");
    background-position: 0px -125px;
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div:hover {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HLqp.png");
    background-position: 0px -77px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Opção número 2**, não sei como é o design do seu png, mas vc pode ter as duas imagens ao mesmo tempo no mesmo lugar. E no `:hover` vc da `display:none` na que está por cima. *(como as duas já estão lá só que uma cobrindo a outra não deve haver delay na troca)*

Veja o exemplo.

```css
.troca {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
}
.troca:hover .hide {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="troca">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRk7blGqe86mAzrflraWsET4_zPz_3JsVH40wzY2tzrBu7phhC7" alt="">
    <img class="hide" src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/2x/arrow-filled.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Tomei a liberdade para adicionar um outro exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/3zezjb59/

Comment: @ValdeirPsr é isso ai! Bem tranquilo de fazer né, essa técnica é antiga e o povo usava para fazer bonecos andando trocando o bg-img ums 30x por segundo rss, mas pra vc ver que até hj as vezes quebra o galho!

Comment: Vlw! []'s.......

Answer (score 2):

A técnica é como o @Hugocsl disse na sua resposta. O que você deve fazer é criar uma única imagem com as duas imagens (sprites) juntas, uma ao lado da outra ou uma em cima da outra.

Ao passar o mouse, você simplesmente irá alterar a posição do background no *eixo X* (se os sprites estiverem lado a lado) ou no *eixo Y* (se estiverem uma em cima da outra).

No meu exemplo irei mostrar um sprite ao lado do outro, alterando a posição no eixo X, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo:**

```css
.banner_home_inferior .owl-next {
  right: -6px;
  background: url(http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/hoverimg.jpg) no-repeat !important;
  
  /* o background-position abaixo é opcional
  já que o background já é posicionado naturalmente
  no topo e à esquerda*/
  /*background-position: 0 0 !important;*/
  height: 89px !important;
  width: 48px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  /* margin-top: -44.5px !important; */
  top: 50% !important;
  font-size: 0 !important;
}

.banner_home_inferior .owl-next:hover {
  background-position: -48px 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_home_inferior">
   <div class="owl-next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bem didática a explicação e a imagem, valeu os créditos []'s